# CMD команда. Удалить файлы в папках и подпапках, за исключением одной папки

Tags: windows, консоль, cmd

Есть команда:

```
Forfiles -p "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads" -s -m *.csv -d -60 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

удаление всех файлов в папке `C:\Users\Admin\Downloads` и подпапках (рекурсивно) `-s`

старше 60 дней `-d -60`

удалять только файлы в формате **csv** `-m *.csv`

Подскажите как дополнить эту команду, поставить исключение, удалять кроме папки `C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Telegram Desktop`

Comment: Думаю можно попробовать добавить условие в `-c "cmd /c del /q @path"`. Например, `if @path <> 'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Telegram Desktop' ...`, что-то в этом вроде

Comment: Полагаю, что перед использованием каталогов надо отфильтровать их. А только потом подать на вход нужной команде. Например, следующим образом. FOR /F "DELIMS=" %i IN ('DIR /S /B /AD C:\Users\* ^|FINDSTR /B /I /V "C:\Users\Telegram Desktop\"') DO @FORFILES /P "%i" /S /M *.csv /D -60 /C "CMD /C DEL /Q @path"